# Why might SQL parameter sniffing have negative performance effect on first execution?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, database-performance, query-performance

I have a SQL 2005 database that is distributed with an application at about 250 different locations. At just one location a stored procedure was timing out. I found that the query within the stored procedure runs instantaneously by itself in SSMS but the sproc takes over 30 seconds to run it. This led me to reading up on parameter sniffing. The articles & forums I've read explain that the execution plan will be created based on the parameter value used the first time you run the stored procedure and therefore may be inefficient for successive runs with different parameter values. Makes sense. What I don't understand is, I have dropped and recreated the stored procedure (even tried "with recompile") and restarted SQL Server, then executed the sproc and it still takes 30+ seconds to run on the first run and successive runs **using the same parameter value every time**. Updating the sproc to copy the parameter value to a local variable *does* fix it, but I don't understand why when I'm only using a single value and all of the parameter sniffing examples pertain to using multiple values for a parameter. Why might it be running slowly in this scenario when the query itself can run in less than 0.01 seconds?

EDIT:

Here is the query:

```
SELECT          bs.pk_EventScheduleID AS EventScheduleID,  
                bs.EventDate, 
                bs.EventDate AS [DisplayEventDate], 
                s.pk_StudentID AS [StudentID],  
                s.fk_FamilyID AS [FamilyID],  
                s.FirstName,  
                s.LastName,  
                bb.DepositDate, 
                [Step1], 
                [Step2], 
                [Step3], 
                [Step4], 
                [Step5], 
                'Required' AS [DatesType],
                bb.IsCancelled
FROM               tbl_EventSchedule bs 
LEFT JOIN (tbl_EventBooking bb  
                INNER JOIN     tbl_Student s ON bb.fk_StudentID = s.pk_StudentID
                INNER JOIN     (Select     fk_EventBookingID,  
                                [AADA95F3-23AA-40BE-9582-BA3847B88367] AS [Step1], 
                                [F188F8A3-8F3C-429B-8F59-C510E1D94AA8] As [Step2], 
                                [1E493583-3961-4ED0-9388-0D1AC4C0EF32] As [Step3], 
                                [8E5E6B19-A863-4D03-BA97-1A2B86F71506] As [Step4], 
                                [0FE5FDA7-DFEC-4E09-AC63-2805AC562AE3] As [Step5] 
                                FROM (SELECT fk_EventBookingID, RequiredDate, GlobalTypeID  
                                       FROM tbl_EventBookingDate 
                                       INNER JOIN tbl_EventDateType ON fk_EventDateTypeID = pk_EventDateTypeID) t 
                                PIVOT 
                                (MAX(RequiredDate) FOR GlobalTypeID IN ([AADA95F3-23AA-40BE-9582-BA3847B88367], 
                                [F188F8A3-8F3C-429B-8F59-C510E1D94AA8], 
                                [1E493583-3961-4ED0-9388-0D1AC4C0EF32], 
                                [8E5E6B19-A863-4D03-BA97-1A2B86F71506], 
                                [0FE5FDA7-DFEC-4E09-AC63-2805AC562AE3])) As pvt 
                               ) bbdRequired 
                ON bb.pk_EventBookingID = bbdRequired.fk_EventBookingID 
                )ON bs.pk_Eventscheduleid = bb.fk_Eventscheduleid 
WHERE               bs.eventdate > @weekDate 
AND                    bs.isdeleted = 0
AND                    (bb.pk_EventBookingID IS NULL OR  
                     ( 
                          bb.IsDeleted = 0 
              --            AND bb.IsCancelled = 0
                      ) 
                 )
```

When executing, the first step is the inner most table join between tbl_EventBookingDate and tbl_EventDateType. Look at the difference between the execution plans when using the sproc param vs. a local variable.

[image]

tbl_EventBookingDate has a total of 5635 records and tbl_EventDateType has 5 records in it. 3,620 and 4,079,740 in the upper execution plan, happen to be the number of records in each table X 724. And 724 is the number of records in tbl_EventSchedule where bs.eventdate > @weekDate and bs.isdeleted = 0. So it seems to be executing the inner query once for each tbl_EventSchedule row when using the sproc parameter?

Comment: Is there a reason why one query plan seems to be referencing a table called "tbl_Event..." and the other is "tbl_Birth..."?

Comment: @etliens No. I changed the names for this example and missed those two occurrences. Thanks.